# Convert type string object to type class object in python

Tags: python, string, class, discord.py

I have some code for a discord bot I am building that I want to make cleaner. Instead of writing a new if statement when a new enemy is made, I would like to check if a user input is already an enemy(class object) and then preform an action on that class object of the same name.

Below is the code for building an enemy.

```
class EnemyCreator:

type = 'enemy'

def __init__(self, name, enemy_type, health, ap):
    self.name = name
    self.enemy_type = enemy_type
    self.health = health
    self.ap = ap
    info = (name + ', ' + str(health) + ', ' + str(ap))
    npc_info.append(info)
```

And here is an example enemy:

```
skeleton = EnemyCreator('Randy Bones', 'skeleton', 100, 2)
```

I have an attack function:

```
def attack(enemy):
    enemy.health = enemy.health - playerChar.ap
    if enemy.health > 0:
        playerChar.health = playerChar.health - enemy.ap
        return ('You attacked ' + enemy.name + '. ' + str(enemy.health) + ' life remaining. \n'
                + enemy.name + ' attacks back! You take ' + str(enemy.ap) + ' damage. You have ' + str(playerChar.health)
                + ' remaining!')
    if enemy.health <= 0:
        return enemy.name + ' has been defeated!'
    if playerChar.health <= 0:
        return 'You died idiot.'
```

Then I have the input checked with this code:

```
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    if message.author != client.user:
        if 'test' in message.content.lower():
            print(npc_info)
        if '!attack' in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send(
                attack(message.content[8::))
```

However, this causes an issue because the object passed into the `attack(enemy)` function is a string, and I need it to be a class object. Any ideas on how to add this functionaliy?

Comment: where do you store the contexts between the messages ? you need to retrieve the Enemy from somewhere ... you can create a EnemyList or just save inside the Enemy class all enemies you created(ugly, but works) and then ask for the enemy that have the name you received in the message ...

Comment: So make an EnemyList, then check if the str of the object in the list = the string, then return the object from the list that matches the string?

Comment: I will propose an answer

Comment: You don't want to convert it into a "class object", you want to convert it to a `EnemyCreator` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I have made a list of all enemy's along side their name. Then I return the index of the corresponding value to the enemies name. Below is what I came up with.

Enemy creation:

```
boss = EnemyCreator('Charles Hammerdick', 'boss', 10000, 200)
npc_list.append(boss)
npc_list.append(boss.name)
```

attack function:

```
def attack(enemy):
for thing in npc_list:
    if str(enemy) in str(thing):
        enemy = (npc_list[npc_list.index(thing) - 1])
        enemy.health = enemy.health - playerChar.ap
        if enemy.health > 0:
            playerChar.health = playerChar.health - enemy.ap
            return ('You attacked ' + enemy.name + '. ' + str(enemy.health) + ' life remaining. \n'
                    + enemy.name + ' attacks back! You take ' + str(enemy.ap) + ' damage. You have ' + str(playerChar.health)
                    + ' remaining!')
        if enemy.health <= 0:
            return enemy.name + ' has been defeated!'
        if playerChar.health <= 0:
            return 'You died idiot.'
```

Comment: It works! Nevertheless, I would advise you to try to split these concepts (player, npc, enemy) into classes, your code is hard to read for someone else or yourself in a couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a way of getting the existing enemies.
I will propose something using an in-memory solution, but for a more robust/scalable solution, you should use a database (sqlite, Postgresql, Mysql), and for easy development, an ORM (SQLalchemy or Django).

An EnemyList would be:

```
class EnemyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._enemies = {}
    def new_enemy(name, enemy_type, health, ap):
        enemy = EnemyCreator(name, enemy_type, health, ap)
        self._enemies[name] = enemy
        return enemy
    def find_enemy(name):
        return self._enemies[name]
```

Then you would need to change your `on_message` function to use it

```
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    if message.author != client.user:
        if 'test' in message.content.lower():
            print(npc_info)
        if '!attack' in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send(
                attack(EnemyList.find_enemy(message.content[8::)))
```

This is the short answer, I won't add here other advice because they are not related to the question but you can also check:

- String Formating
- OO -> The attack function maybe should be a method of a playerChar object?
- The DB thing I already spoke of.

Comment: Instead of a list, why not use a dictionary, where the name of each enemy is the key?

Comment: @Jasmijn, sure thing! I changed it, thanks for the feedback!